Как создать событие когда меняется месяц в календаре WPF
Как создать события нажимая на кнопки которые указаны на скриншоте. WPF


При смене отображаемой даты возникает событие
<Calendar DisplayDateChanged="Calendar_DisplayDateChanged"/>

Изменение даты отслеживается через свойства аргумента события CalendarDateChangedEventArgs e.AddedDate и CalendarDateChangedEventArgs e.RemovedDate

Спасибо большое! Работает)
